# Validate uniqueness of an item on individual user level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, github-api

I have a simple Rails 4 app calling the GitHub API to recreate, on a basic level, the Repositories page. On my calls to the API I am parsing the JSON and saving it in my database. The problem I'm having is that I want to validate the uniqueness of the repository name, but I only want the names to be unique for each user. As of now if I look at one user's page it saves everything fine, but if the next user I look at has anything named the same it will not save that repository to the database.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :profile_id
```

This will enforce uniqueness per profile, which it sounds like is what you're looking for.